# How to get rid of this "The import com.google.gwt cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I'm new to Google Web Toolkit (using as plug-in in Eclipse). Why the java class under com.demo.project.client is showing error---

```
The import com.google.gwt cannot be resolved.
```

How to resolve it? I guess some path is missing.

Comment: what is your classpath ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GWT Library is missing in your classpath. [Here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project%27s_classpath%3F) is a tutorial how to add the library to the classpath.

EDIT: link fixed

Comment: Link working now, +1 for nice simple answer. I've set it loads of times, and will probably forget the next time I have to do it!

Comment: stackoverflow breaks the eclipse links sometimes .. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Add GWT library to your classpath.